# Adding a new font family to Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

How can I add a new font family to twitter bootstrap just the way they do it? They use something called woff. I'm trying to add roboto condensed to the .css file. How can I do it like they do it with the woff thing?

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url("//themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v6/u-WUoqrET9fUeobQW7jkRT8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff") format('woff');
}
```

I searched everywhere, but cant find how to do the woff thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a new CSS file. Call it `custom.css`. Link the CSS file inside your CSS tag as external CSS file. There add your `@font-face` code as in:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'OpenSans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url("//themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v6/u-WUoqrET9fUeobQW7jkRT8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff") format('woff');
}
```

Your `@font-face` code seems to be missing some fonts/file. You can use [Font Squirel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to convert your font file and generate the corresponding CSS file. Use that block of CSS file.

And then use OpenSans in your font-family css.

I hope it helps

Comment: Actually I want to know how to do the woff for ROBOTO. How are they doing the .woff thing?

Comment: Use http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator this to conver your font to the other format needed. It will generate all the format including the css file for you